# android - startActivityForResult from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

can you help me, if there is any way, how to call method startActivityForResult(..) from class extends ArrayAdapter?

Thanks.

EDIT: ADDED CODE OF ARRAYADAPTER:

There is code of MyAdapter class:

`public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {`

```
public static final String bundle_text = "some_text";

public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MyAdapterItem> data) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    // ...

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            int id = 1;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong(MyAdapter.bundle_text, id);

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

All works, but from ArrayAdapter class is not possible to call startActivityForResult, I can call only startActivty.
But after MyNewActivity is finished, I would like to refresh listview, but I do not know how, when I cannot call startActivityForResult.

Comment: can you paste some of your addapter code ?

Comment: startActivityForResult is a method of Activity. You need to call it in the scope of an Activity subclass or a child class of the Activity subclass. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want show in listview same data. After click of one row - start new activity - until this, it is OK. And then (after new activity is closed) I want refresh list view). But there is problem, that I do not know, when and how to refresh listview adter closed new activity.

Answer (score 1):

This a common misconception (as is old thread, I will just give an outline)

1. Adapter is only for data to list view - it does return a view as in your getView for a row, but doesn't really handle any GUI events - those are done in activity. In fact, if adapter is loading a lot of rows from internet or database it should be done outside the UI thread.
2. ACTIVITY IS FOR EVENTS. You attach a click listener to a listview within your activity. Then there is no problem calling e.g. a detail edit activity - it is all on UI thread. So no problem starting an activity from UI thread.
3. PROBLEM OF UPDATING ADAPTER! If you back return from detail activity you will find the list is NOT updated as adapter was NOT updated. To do this, start detail Activity for RESULT. Don't clutter up the detail "form" with any adapter stuff. In fact, you may choose to return the POJO that was created or edited in detail record, and not bother with the database at all.
4. Now in your activity you listen for onActivityResult() and do the insert into the adapter (and database backend if you have e.g. SQLite in app), then notify Data changed for list view. It will update the list view automatically.

PERFORMANCE can be an issue if listview is reloaded. In most cases you can get away by adding to adapter and simply notify the list view data is changed. Since data display is "incremental" you may have edited row 3 of rows 1 - 5 shown. Then list view will only refresh those 1-5 rows display positions. But if you reload say 500 rows when only 1 is changed you could get performance issues :)

Comment: This a nice explanation, but if I inflate the view of my ListAdapter and do all the needed work, but attach listeners in activity, then it crashes because onCreate() probably hasn't seen the results of ListAdapter  getView() function. What should I do, because attaching a listener in getView() that activates another activity for result simply doesn't work at all :(